# Python pandas refer to column with "/"

Tags: python, excel, debugging, pandas

I am reading data from an excel file using pandas. I want to view data only in a certain region where it has been visited.

I get the following error for the Visit column which is labeled in the spreadsheet as 'VISIT(Y/N)':

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'VISIT'
```

This is the code I am using. How do I get python to interpret 'VISIT(Y/N)' as a column?

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_excel("myFile.xlsx")

data = df[(df.REGION == "AMER") & df.VISIT(Y/N) == "Y")]

print(list(df))
print(data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `df.VISIT(Y/N)`, which you've found is invalid, do this:

```
df['VISIT(Y/N)'] == "Y"
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas can create proxy attribute accessors based on column names if and only if the names are valid Python syntax. Having parenthesis or slash is not allowed in Python for identifiers, so that particular column can be only accessed through `df['VISIT(Y/N)']`